# How is Hadoop different from database?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cassandra, nosql

I was doing a case study on Spotify. I found out that Spotify uses Cassandra as a DB and also Hadoop. My question is, how is Hadoop different from a database. What type of files does Hadoop datanode stores? Why every corporation has DB and Hadoop as well. I know Hadoop is not a DB but what is it used for if there is DB cluster to save data?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not a database at all. Hadoop is a set of tools for distributed storage and processing, such as distributed filesystem (HDFS), MapReduce framework libraries, YARN resource manager.

Other tools like Hive, Spark, Pig, Giraph, sqoop, etc, etc can use Hadoop or it's components.  For example Hive is a database. It uses HDFS for storing it's data and MapReduce framework primitives for building query execution graph.